# Eclipse CDT does not index code between #if .... #endif

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am using CDT version 9.x.x with eclipse Neon. I am using the CDT APIs to get the function calls inside of a function. When a conditional compilation statement as below is encountered this version of CDT is not getting the function calls inside `#if` statement rather gets the call in `#else`. In the below example it extracts `func3()` but `func2()` is expected as the macro `NLC_LS_AVL` is defined to 1 in the header file and if we preprocess the C file the function call inside `#if` i.e. `func2()`, by the pre-processor.

The same code works in eclipse Indigo and CDT 8.0.2 where the function calls inside `#if` are extracted i.e. `func2()` is extracted.

Is there any addtional configuration that needs to be taken care for CDT 9.X.X for it get the right active code for conditional compilation statements? If so can anyone suggest?

Exmaple:

```
\#if (NLC_LS_AVL == 1)  
  &ensp;func2(); <br>
\#else<br>
 &ensp;func3();<br>
\#endif
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Try to rebuild your index (right-click on project -> Index -> Rebuild - sometimes the index does not see a change to a header file, especially if the header file is not in the project. HTH